# 2 Images in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want 2 images in my TableViewCell but I don't know how and I don't know if it's possible but  the idea is.
![enter image description here][1]

Is this possible? If it is, how can I do this?

I googled but couldn't find the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: Did you use custom UITableViewCell

Comment: Thank you both for your reactions but my images doesn't show up. So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what this is looking for. Check below project

https://github.com/slysid/iOS/tree/master/TwoImages

Bharath

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I am looking for I just need 2 little pictures in a tableviewcell. Look at my image in the headpost. But still thanks for helping! :)

Comment: You mean the image next to label "Name" and image next to date?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean

Comment: check the github code. I have modified the code on how to add the images programatically. You can also do the same thing via XIB.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but thank you. It works now.